# Notice: Undefined index backdrop_path

Tags: php, json, api

i want display the backdrop_path of the movie but i get this error

> Notice: Undefined index: backdrop_path in /..../public_html/movie.php on line 167

I have added

```
print_r($tmdbResult);
```

to see the content of  `$tmdbResult`. I want to display just `backdrop_path`.

```
Array
(
[movie_results] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
[adult] => 
[backdrop_path] => /mbA7SCtJoFTactP1lDHA055qCf.jpg
                [genre_ids] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 35
                        [1] => 28
                    )

                [id] => 261392
                [original_language] => en
                [original_title] => American Ultra
                [overview] => A stoner and his girlfriend's sleepy, small-town existence is disrupted when his past comes back to haunt him in the form of a government operation set to wipe him out.
                [release_date] => 2015-08-21
                [poster_path] => /6oGHH27nqaLGfpcgYRIZYSJs7AD.jpg
                [popularity] => 3.509263
                [title] => American Ultra
                [video] => 
                [vote_average] => 5.6
                [vote_count] => 134
            )

    )

[person_results] => Array
    (
    )

[tv_results] => Array
    (
    )

[tv_episode_results] => Array
    (
    )

[tv_season_results] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

The code i use is

```
ini_set("display_errors",1);


$tmdbResponse = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$tmdbResult = json_decode($tmdbResponse, true );
$backdrop_path = $tmdbResult['movie_results']['backdrop_path'];
$smarty->assign("backdrop_path",$backdrop_path);
print_r($tmdbResult);
```

Comment: `$tmdbResult['movie_results'][0]['backdrop_path'];` `[0], Carl`

Comment: i replace that with $backdrop_path = $tmdbResult['movie_results']['backdrop_path']; ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you're getting a numeric index, because the result can contain multiple movies. In this case you're getting just one.

All you need to do is access the array like this @u_mulder said:

```
$bp = $tmdbResult['movie_results'][0]['backdrop_path'];
```

The `[0]` meaning that in case you get multiple results, just need to change that index to access the others. May be you shoulds think of a foreach loop, unless for some reason of yours, you KNOW you'll always get ONE single movie, in that case, hardcode your `$bp = $tmdbResult['movie_results'][0]['backdrop_path'];` no problem.